# "Microsoft Access database Engine" Hresult: 0X80004005 Description: "External Table is not in expected Format."

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I am having an issue while i am trying to load data into table from an .xlsx file using SSIS 2014,
previously i was able to load the data as i received the file in .xls version, but now recently i am receiving the file in .xlsx file (i somehow came to know that they are generating file of OFFICE 16).
what all scenarios i have tested :

1.Opening the file manually and Save/Save As it and load the table - it is working but, not recommended on daily basis as i need that to be automated.

2.In DFT i am using this connection string is`Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\a.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;`
-- it is not working still

3.Tried opening the Excel file using a C# code (Script Task), i have tried the above connection and also some other version like changing extended version in the connection string which i mentioned above:

- `Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;`
- `Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 xml;`
- `Extended Properties=HTML import;`

  then i got an error saying

> could not find installable ISAM.

did not understand what error is this !!

4.I opened the .xlsx file in notepad, i noticed that `"xl/workbook.xml"` has changed to `"[Content_Types].xml"`  when i just open the file and press save button. then the file is able to access. - did not get any clarity on this scenario.

PS: I am using SQL Server 2014 and SSIS 2014 in Windows Server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have done all the preparations including installing [Microsoft Access 2010 Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10910)

Try using the following connection string from DFT (*added double quotes as Xml keyword*):

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="C:\Users\a.xlsx";Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1";
```

Comment: The same error is still coming, "External table is not in Expected format ",